# Defining a graph dynamically in C

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, graph, malloc

I am constructing a graph(un-directed) in C. Graph nodes are struct:

```
struct graphNode{
    int val;
    int neighborCount;
    struct graphNode *neighbors[MaxN]; //this is adjacency list
}
```

Now, I have to initialize n nodes of a graph dynamically or I need an array of structs `graphNodes`. And then, for each node, I have to initialize neighbor array to NULL initially. I would later add neighbors to it as the nodes are added. What's the correct way of defining graph with given requirements? I have done following but I don't think this is correct. I am new to C.

```
struct graphNode *createGraph(int nodes){
        struct graphNode *graph = malloc(nodes * sizeof(*graph));
        for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++){
                graph[i]->n = malloc(MAXN * sizeof(struct graphNode *));
        }
        return graph;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<MAXN;i++)` --> `for(int i=0;i<nodes;i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `graphNode` struct contains the array of neighbor pointers, all you need to do is allocate space for an array of `graphNode`, which is what the first `malloc` does.

Given that you want all of the neighbor pointers initialized to `NULL`, I would change the `malloc` to a `calloc` (which auto-zeros the memory). The resulting code looks like this

```
struct graphNode *createGraph(int nodes){
    struct graphNode *graph = calloc(nodes, sizeof(*graph));
    return graph;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't I need to malloc neighbor array for each Node? Why not?

Comment: @Neo `sizeof(*graph)` includes the array of neighbors. So you *are* allocating an array of neighbor pointers.